# PAYDAY 2 - Fresh Install

Tags: payday-2

Recently my PAYDAY has been crashing a lot because I have been installing and uninstalling a lot of mods. I think that because I have tweaked with the PAYDAY files so much it is starting to crash. I basically want to do a fresh install of the whole game by right clicking on PAYDAY on Steam and clicking 'Delete Local Files'. However I wanted to know if this would also erase my progress.

Comment: It shouldn't. You may wish to read [this article](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=170416480) for more details though.

Comment: Well it did work but the crashing has increased in the new version! I am going to stop playing as it crashes after 1 simple bank job.